# 「○○は草」とはどういう意味でしょうか？

Tags: meaning, slang, internet-slang

Abemaの麻雀チャンネルを見ていたら、人のコメントの一部または全部をコピーして、最後に「は草」を付けて送信する人がいました。

例えば、コメント欄がとても盛り上がっていた時に「コメント読みてえのに多すぎて読めねえんだよ だから各自で控えろ」というコメントがありました。

これに対して

> コメントを控えろは草

と送ってきました。

このようなことをいろんなコメントでずっと繰り返していました。これはただの荒らしかもしれないけど、何か意味があるなら知りたいです。

Comment: Related: [What does the internet slang "草生えた" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9940/5010)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

草 is Internet slang that means "laugh", "laughable", and 「笑える」,「うける」,「面白い」 in Japanese.

"w" is Internet slang that means "laugh", "laughable". People use it like "wwwwwwww" when they want to emphasize "w", and "wwwwwwww" looks like grass growing. So 草 came to mean "laugh", "laughable" as Internet slang.

Source:https://kw-note.com/internet-slang/kusa/

Comment: probably also because it sounds close to クス

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky No. It simply comes from how it looks. It's an abbreviation of 草生える.

Answer (score 4):

草は、インターネットスラングで笑うの意味である"w"の見た目から来ています。www←これが草のように見えるため。
つまり、(笑)と同義です。