# What does チビバージョンは草 sentence means?

Tags: meaning, internet-slang

I commented in a Japanese Youtube video of a game.
I said not to release it globally because it's just a chibi version of an already released game and they replied to me with チビバージョンは草. And when I used a translator it says "chibi of grass". I guess it's wrong.
Can you help me plz?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60234/%e3%81%af%e8%8d%89-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e6%84%8f%e5%91%b3%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b

Comment: ↑is correct. posted sentence means "They released chibi(tiny) version lol"

Answer (score 2):

チビバージョンは草 basically means "(the phrase) チビバージョン is funny", but said in a slangy way. See the following questions for the meaning of this 草.

- [「○○は草」とはどういう意味でしょうか？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60234/5010)
- [What does the internet slang "草生えた" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9940/5010)

Perhaps you wanted to say something like "mini version (of the game)"? Then you chose a wrong word. チビ is used to describe someone's height, and it tends have a negative/pejorative overtone unless it's used to refer to [this art style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chibi_(slang)).