# What does a w at the end of sentences signify?

Tags: pronunciation, colloquial-language

Sometimes I see people attaching a `w` at the end of sentences (or multiple `w`s):

> なんか知らない間に人がめっちゃ増えてるｗ

This is in an informal context, usually while chatting. And sometimes, just:

> wwwww

What is that `w` doing there? How do I read it?

Comment: see also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46789/5010

Comment: @naruto thanks, that should probably be included in the dupe's answers as well (since it asks for pronunciation as well)