# Reading of 笑 in the meaning of lol/heh

Tags: readings, interjections

What is the reading of 笑 when used as a “lol” or “heh” interjection? Is it わらい or something shorter?

Is the reading the same when written as “w”? What if it’s repeated like 笑笑 or wwww?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You usually do not have to read it out loud, but if you do need to, you can read it as わらい. When 笑 is enclosed in parentheses (i.e., `(笑)`), it can be read かっこわらい, too.

In slangy contexts わら is also possible, but it may sound derogatory or otaku-like.

Related: [Pronunciation of「ww」(笑い)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46789/5010)